# Debugging without symbols?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have the simple .c file that is supposed to fail(I know where it fails, I put the bug in there intentionally):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s argument\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char *hello = "hello";
  *hello = 'H';

  fprintf(stdout, "%s, %s!\n", hello, argv[1]);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Part 1)** I save it as "hello.c" and compile without debugging flags by `gcc hello.c -o hello`.

Then, I wish to go line by line through the main function. I try to use gdb as follows:

1. Run `gdb ./hello`
2. Set breakpoint by `break main`
3. Run `run 123`
4. `s` -> fails

Here is the outcome:

```
(gdb) info func
All defined functions:

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000000568  _init
0x0000000000000590  fprintf@plt
0x00000000000005a0  __cxa_finalize@plt
0x00000000000005b0  _start
0x00000000000005e0  deregister_tm_clones
0x0000000000000620  register_tm_clones
0x0000000000000670  __do_global_dtors_aux
0x00000000000006b0  frame_dummy
0x00000000000006ba  main
0x0000000000000740  __libc_csu_init
0x00000000000007b0  __libc_csu_fini
0x00000000000007b4  _fini
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6be
(gdb) r
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Debugging/hello

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000080006be in main ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
__fprintf (stream=0x7fffff3ec680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=0x80007c4 "Usage: %s argument\n") at fprintf.c:27
27      fprintf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Why does this happen? Why does it fail like this by trying to find a file fprintf? Thought the preprocessed headers should deal with the required implementation code.

**Part 2)** When I however compile with the `-g`, it works for some reason. But running the program in gdb does not yield a segmentation fault as expected :/ Why?

Again, see:

```
$ ./hello 123
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but

```
(gdb) run 123
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/NichlasDesktop/Documents/uni/Compsys/Exercises/Debugging/exercise_code/hello 123
Hello, 123!
[Inferior 1 (process 632) exited normally]
```

Comment: "But running the program in gdb does not yield a segmentation fault as expected". Your expectation is not correct. Writing to a string constant is undefined behaviour. Note, UB does not mean "will always crash". It means we don't know for sure what the behaviour will be - it can crash in some cases, in may appear to work in some cases, and it may have some other behaviour altogether.

Comment: look at *valgrind* to check your memory accesses and more (memory leak, non initialized memory etc), it is a very helpful set of tools, use it even you think your code is ok

Comment: `char *hello = "hello"; *hello = 'H';` is undefined behavior and you cannot rely on it.

Comment: `char *hello = "hello";` is a literal string. It is readonly.

Comment: Thanks, bruno and kaylum. I now know which tool I can use and that UB does not always mean failure. However, can someone comment on part 1 of the OP - failing when debugging a program without the `-g` flag

Comment: It's trying to step into `fprintf` but you don't have debugging info for `libc`. It's not an error in your program. Just gdb telling you it doesn't have debugging info for that function.

Comment: @kaylum oh okay. Can't you tell it to step over it? Why does it have to use debug info to step into that function anyway - isn't the necessary code/static libraries linked together inside the executable that I am debugging

Comment: You are the one that told it to step into it by entering `s` :-). If you don't want to step into it then use `n` instead.

Comment: @Landstalker You should treat it as read only, but it's not required to be.

Answer (score 2):

> Part 1)
>
> `s -> fails`

Without debugging information, `gdb` is unable to map instructions to source code - file paths and line numbers. The `s`/`step` command tells `gdb` to execute instructions that correspond to the current statement in the source language. `gdb` has no way of telling what that is, so it continues till wherever in code the source position ("SPOS") information is available. That happens to be in libc where fprintf is defined. However the source code for fprintf is not available in your environment, hence that message.

You could step through the individual instructions using the `si`/`stepi` command, this does not need debugging information to be present.

You did not show what happens if you continue execution from that point, I suspect it would eventually hit the segmentation fault.

> Why does this happen? Why does it fail like this by trying to find a file fprintf? Thought the preprocessed headers should deal with the required implementation code.

That is not what headers are. They don't contain source code.

> Part 2) When I however compile with the -g, it works for some reason. But running the program in gdb does not yield a segmentation fault as expected :/ Why?

`gdb` or any other debugger would arrange for the executable text segment to be mapped private instead of shared as in the usual run case (`mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE` instead of `MAP_SHARED`). This is because the debugger needs the text segment to be writable so that instructions can be overwritten to insert breakpoints etc.

The "hello" you put in there is a constant string literal that is stored in the read-only text segment of the executable. This is why writing to it causes a segmentation fault during the normal run - the text segment is mapped shared. Inside the debugger however the text segment is mapped private, so you are able to write to it.