# gdb dubugger raise an error everytime I type run command someting related with bfd

Tags: c, gdb

I'am learning how to use gdb but the problem is when I use run command it tells me :
 [screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7cg8.png)

```
BFD: /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/3f/e0a4f36db175f0f8311cbd2178682faf0ef754.debug: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_aranges
BFD: /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/3f/e0a4f36db175f0f8311cbd2178682faf0ef754.debug: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_aranges
warning: File "/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/3f/e0a4f36db175f0f8311cbd2178682faf0ef754.debug" has no build-id, file skipped
```

The expected output according to a book that I am reading

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1".
```

I ignored this errors at the beginning but later I can't debug some code like strcpy function I don't see `Pending breakpoint "strcpy" resolved` and according to book this also have to make a forth breakpoint.

How can I fix this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us, how did you compile your source code? If you are using an IDE try to compile your code in terminal first.

Comment: I compiled it with gcc (the file is written with C) the command in terminal "gcc -g  file_name.c "

Comment: Can you paste the command you used to compile the source code in terminal?

Comment: "gcc -g file_name.c"

Comment: You can't use a debugger if you do not provide the debugging symbols at compile time. This is why you add a debugging parameters to the command line like `gcc -g -gdwarf-2 file_name.c`. Then you start the `gdb` in terminal. You will get a shell where you 1st load the file `file a.out` and then 2nd you start the program `start`. Then you can step through the program using `s` + **Enter**.

Comment: take a look at this question to see how to present yours (code, compile command, gdb interaction): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069562

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here because symbols are successfully read it tells me  **"Reading symbols from ./a.out...done"** then something else I set the "-o" parameter with gcc to generate a  "file_name" (even without it I still get same error) till here everything is ok the break points work, examine till I wrote a program with ""strcpy()" function and according to the book I read when I run the program after setting a 3 breakpoints I had to see something like "Pending breakpoint "strcpy"  resolved" and then gdb set auto cause it's an external lib  so hope you understand thanks

Comment: This can be caused by an [old version of the bfd library](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23919) (which is bundled with gdb). I'm not sure why the /usr/lib/debug files you have are not compatible with the gdb that you have. Do you recall if you downloaded either the debuginfo files or gdb from some other place than your linux distro?

Comment: No it comes with kali linux so what I have to do ?

Comment: I'd try building a recent version of gdb from source https://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/releases/ . It has some library dependencies, but those can be downloaded and installed with `sudo apt-get build-dep gdb` (I believe Kali has mostly the same set of packages as Debian).